# Terraform Azuread provider Authorizer Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-azure

My GitLab CI/CD pipeline is throwing a Terraform Azuread provider authoriser error which has become a major blocker for me and I simply can't find a way round it.

My Terraform configuration includes a **data.tf** file which has the following single line entry:

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}
```

I also have a **provider.tf** file, the content of which includes the following azuread provider block:

```
provider "azuread" {
   tenant_id = "#TenantID#"
   use_cli = "false"
}
```

Running the GitLab CI/CD pipeline, it throws the below error:

```
Error: no Authorizer could be configured, please check your configuration

with provider ["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread"],
on provider.tf line 29, in provider "azuread":
29: provider "azuread" {
```

If I exclude the data.tf file from my terraform configuration or comment out its single line entry, the pipeline runs without throwing any errors. What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do to get the pipeline run successfully, upon inclusion of the data.tf file?

Comment: **Data Source: azuread_client_config** data source to access the configuration of the AzureAD provider. Then why again you are using **provider "azuread"** both are same doin same work.

Comment: You need to authenticate with AD: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data Source: azuread_client_config**

Use this data source to access the configuration of the AzureAD provider.

**#This is while Terraform authenticating via the Azure CLI**

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

output "object_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

**#Configure the Azure Active Directory Provider**

```
provider "azuread" {

  # NOTE: Environment Variables can also be used for Service Principal authentication

  # client_id     = "..."
  # client_secret = "..."
  # tenant_id     = "..."
}
```

So would suggest you remove `data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}` line from `data.tf` file if you are using `provider azuread {}` in provider.tf file. Because you are already authenticating with Service Principle so there is no point of using **data source of azuread**.

You can also refer this [***Documention***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs) regarding the `Data Sources` and `Resources` supported by the Azure Active Directory Provider

Comment: Great input @RahulKumarShaw-MT. I commented out the data block in the data.tf file and applied the proposed changes in the provider block and that enabled the pipeline to run without reporting the earlier error.  Unfortunately though, it's now introduced another Error as follows: [[ Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in $PATH. ]] Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Try with az upgrade to use the latest version of AZ cli and then check ,let me know if you are still facing any issue.

Comment: Try with az upgrade where exactly RahulKumarShaw? The error is indicating that Azure CLI isn’t installed, meaning no az commands will be recognised. How therefore do you run an az upgrade command in the pipeline?

Comment: Ohh ! Sorry I thought you are running in visual in studio. Use only use-cli=false which was working for you. Don't include client ID,client secret, in azuread provider , just remove data source from data.tf file.

Comment: No worries at all RahulKumarShaw and thanks for the further suggestion. Only problem is I already have "use_cli" set to false in the azuread provider block of my provider.tf file.........yet still getting that error. The actuall block is made up of my client_secret, client_id, tenant_id and finally use_cli attributes you see.

Comment: Yes correct, because you are authenticate with service principle so you need to set use_cli as false .hope that solve your issue.

Comment: Nope, simply setting the use_cli attribute to false never resolved the issue Az CLI error. I did eventually resolve it by setting a default image at the top of my .gitlab-ci.yml file to pull down an Azure CLI docker container from our corporate registry (which being a recent starter in my organisation I was unfortunately never aware existed).